# FireFox video flashing white boxes

Tags: video, firefox, flash

I moved to Ubuntu 11 x64 abt 2 weeks ago from Windows 7 x64. I noticed that some videos on FireFox flashes white/black boxes here & there

[image]

Boxes appear flashing about even before the video started

[image]

Above, even the scrollbar/time indicator is affected, the right side is also flashing black boxes ...

In Chrome, I have yet to experience this. Isit a FireFox problem? Or perhaps Flash x64 beta on Linux (Adobe didnt have a stable Flash for Linux x64)?

Comment: I used to have a similar problem on Fedora 14. Which version of flash player do you have ??

Comment: @funkymonk. I've observed the same symptoms as described by @jiewmeng.  about:plugins in both ff in chrome show  flash version 10.2.159.  As described by @jiewmeng, this happens in FF but *not* in chrome (hope you don't mind my stepping in).

Comment: @funkymonk, I have 10.2 r159

Comment: This is a known bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/761074 and duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resolved through the comments, not quite but its a bug

> This is a known bug. See
>   http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/…
>   and duplicates. – @ali1234